# Building DOJO in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, dojo

I have included dojo build in my eclipse workspace. Everytime I hit clean it takes a lot of time to build this DOJO project.

I do not want to uncheck it everytime from list of projects to clean since this is very inconvenient, also tried disabling xml and JS validations.

Anybody has any ideas how to get around this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have added the dojo library folder in build path in eclipse.

right click on the folder containing the dojo js file and go to "Build Path" and then click "Remove from Build path".

Please remember, normal folder are not built. This also means that if you have a folder containing .java file but is not part of build path then the .java files inside it won't be compiled.

Hope that resolves your issue.

Comment: netbeans and such editors suffers same issue (also for php projects). Problem is that the dojotoolkit adds some 5k+ files to project and indexing / verification / intellisences will traverse each file. Either IDE should have an 'ignore path' setting as this answer suggests. If not, try using the built-checkout (minified dojo version) instead.